# Trouble editing Path for Environment Variables

Tags: environment-variables

I'm having trouble editing the environment variable Path value in Windows 10 and can't seem to get it right, despite adding both %JAVA_HOME%\bin and C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin

Do I need to add it/change it in a different way?

I've tried either/or and in cmd when I try javac, it still doesn't recognize it in command prompt. I also don't get the Variable Name, Variable Value for Path, I just get the registry. Does that matter?

Images of command prompt, JAVA_HOME, and Path Registry in album linked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPxA7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The JRE does not contain the java complier.

Update your path settings to the JDK instead of the JRE